# iOS: Is there any way to clear AvPlayer streaming data?

Tags: ios, caching, streaming, core-audio, avplayer

I have an app streaming audio from a shout cast server. It streams ok most of the time, however I've noticed the documents and data of the app in Settings > General > Usage is going up whenever I use the app. The app itself is only 776kb but the data has gone from 1.3 mb to 1.5 mb after 30 mins of streaming. Is this due to streamed audio being cached with the AVPlayer? How can I stop this happening or at least delete the cached audio when the app is killed? Also, if I do not resolve this will my app be rejected from the app store? Many thanks.

Comment: Did you find solution, i am facing same problem too. If u find any solution please let me know

Comment: Hey there, I did find a solution, but its not a great solution if your app is storing any other data, in my app delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method I am running the following code (which I found online somewhere, it's not mine, but I cannot remember where):


`code` if ([filemgr removeItemAtPath: [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Library/Caches"] error: NULL]  == YES)
        NSLog (@"Remove successful");
    else
        NSLog (@"Remove failed");
    
  
}

`code`

Comment: self.avPlayer = nil; - for me this is solution, just nil for your player. But after alloc again.